# WHERE NOT EXISTS for counting

Tags: sql, sql-server

UPDATE:

Why does it work in this scenario?

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nS7y4Td2)

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    ID INT,
    code VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, code)
VALUES 
    (1, 'e11'), 
    (1, 'e11'),
    (1, 'e18'), 
    (1, 'e19'), 
    (1, 'e19'), 
    (1, 'i50'), 
    (1, 'i63'),
    (1, 'i25'), 
  
    (2, 'e10'),
    (2, 'e11'),
    (2, 'e12'),
    (2, 'e13'),
    (2, 'e14'),
    (2, 'i51'), 
    (2, 'i63'),
    (2, 'i26'), 
  
    (3, 'e10'),
    (3, 'e10'), 
    (3, 'e12'),
    (3, 'e13'),
    (3, 'e14'),
    (3, 'i51'), 
    (3, 'i63'),
    (3, 'i26')
```

Answer is ID 2 and 3

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id 
FROM MyTable AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM MyTable AS inner_t1
    WHERE t1.id = inner_t1.id
    AND inner_t1.code IN ('e10')
  )
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM MyTable AS inner_t1
    WHERE t1.id = inner_t1.id
    AND inner_t1.code IN ('i51')
  )
```

Answer is ID 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
FROM MyTable AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM MyTable AS inner_t1
    WHERE t1.id = inner_t1.id
    AND inner_t1.code IN ('e10')
  )
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM MyTable AS inner_t1
    WHERE t1.id = inner_t1.id
    AND inner_t1.code IN ('i51')
  )
```

Because they are mutually exclusive...

---

---

---

I want to count how many distinct IDs do not have both `order_date` entries ('2023-06-01','2023-06-02') using `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.
The answer should be 2 (ID 2 and 3) but instead it says 1.

When using `WHERE EXISTS` the answer is 1 which is correct (ID 1)

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3tDEwxmc)

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    order_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id INT,
    order_date DATE
);
INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, customer_id, order_date)
VALUES (1, 1, '2023-06-01'),
       (2, 1, '2023-06-01'),
       (3, 1, '2023-06-02'),
       (4, 1, '2023-06-03'),
       (5, 2, '2023-06-01'),
       (6, 2, '2023-06-04'),
       (7, 2, '2023-06-07'),
       (8, 3, '2023-06-08'),
       (9, 3, '2023-06-09');
```

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.customer_id) 
FROM Orders AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Orders AS inner_t1
    WHERE t1.customer_id = inner_t1.customer_id
    AND inner_t1.order_date IN ( '2023-06-01')
  )
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Orders AS inner_t1
    WHERE t1.customer_id = inner_t1.customer_id
    AND inner_t1.order_date IN ( '2023-06-02')
);
```

I also tried using `NOT IN` but that does not work.

Why is that?

Comment: Customer 2 has an entry `2023-06-01` so the correct answer is 1 !

Comment: Protip: if `COUNT(...)` ever gives unexpected results, replace the aggregate functions with `SELECT *` so you can see the actual raw rows prior to aggregation.

Comment: Maybe you want `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: @SelVazi Correct, but i combined two dates using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` + `AND NOT EXISTS`. So i am searching for distinct `customer_id`s who do not have both `order_date`s in their data entries.

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. use HAVING.

Comment: So, combining `WHERE EXISTS` + `AND EXISTS` as seen in db<>fiddle does work with the answer 1 for `customer_id` 1.

Comment: OR NOT EXISTS [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GUDUJBct)

Comment: What's the logic behind the dates? Why `06-01` and `06-02` specifically? You may be able to use window functions like LAG to find orders that don't happen in consecutive days.

Comment: @PonderStibbons That works perfect but confuses me. My interpretation of this query would be as follows: Either not `order_date` '2023-06-01' OR not `order_date` '2023-06-02'..

Comment: [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): `not (01 and 02)` = `not 01 or not 02`

Answer (score 2):

This is an other way to do it using `group by` and `having` clause :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
  FROM Orders AS t1
  GROUP BY customer_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN order_date IN ( '2023-06-01', '2023-06-02') THEN order_date END ) < 2
) AS s
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/MxMaV4uj)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` to get all customers where have orders in both of the dates and than select all which are not in the list:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT customer_id) 
from orders 
where customer_id not in (
select t1.customer_id FROM Orders AS t1 join Orders t2 on t1.customer_id =t2.customer_id 
  where t1.order_date= '2023-06-01' and t2.order_date = '2023-06-02')
```

Comment: He wants to use WHERE NOT EXISTS clause in his query.

Comment: This actually works. But the logic of `WHERE EXISTS` is easier to understand. Why does it work when counting distinct `customer_id`s that have both `order_date`s in their data entries but not when trying to count how many distinct  `customer_id`s do not have both `order_date`s?The logic does not make sense to me.

Comment: *But the logic of WHERE EXISTS is easier to understand.* really?

Comment: *Why does it work when counting distinct customer_ids that have both order_dates in their data entries but not when trying to count how many distinct customer_ids do not have both order_dates?* because your Logic is wrong. You only get customer which have no orders on both dates